# How to convert numbers to words?

Tags: javascript

How can I use Javascript for converting numbers to words?  The display requires Indian rupees and paise format.

Comment: A quick google search yielded this - http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vbscript/CurrencyToWord.aspx?msg=2159336 . It is in vbscript though but it will give you an idea.

Comment: It would help if you showed what you have tried to do, and what algorithm you are using, else it sounds like you don't care to do this, you just want someone to give you some code for free.

Comment: @James Black: agreed. However OP did ask "plz guide me", not "plz send me teh codez" ;)

Comment: Is there any php function for this....

Comment: I doubt there be some straight forward function for it.. coz standard functions are not generally currency dependent..:P

Comment: Here is the same question (asked a year later), but with more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529934/javascript-numbers-to-words.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no built-in function.

```
function test_skill() {
    var junkVal=document.getElementById('rupees').value;
    junkVal=Math.floor(junkVal);
    var obStr=new String(junkVal);
    numReversed=obStr.split("");
    actnumber=numReversed.reverse();

    if(Number(junkVal) >=0){
        //do nothing
    }
    else{
        alert('wrong Number cannot be converted');
        return false;
    }
    if(Number(junkVal)==0){
        document.getElementById('container').innerHTML=obStr+''+'Rupees Zero Only';
        return false;
    }
    if(actnumber.length>9){
        alert('Oops!!!! the Number is too big to covertes');
        return false;
    }

    var iWords=["Zero", " One", " Two", " Three", " Four", " Five", " Six", " Seven", " Eight", " Nine"];
    var ePlace=['Ten', ' Eleven', ' Twelve', ' Thirteen', ' Fourteen', ' Fifteen', ' Sixteen', ' Seventeen', ' Eighteen', ' Nineteen'];
    var tensPlace=['dummy', ' Ten', ' Twenty', ' Thirty', ' Forty', ' Fifty', ' Sixty', ' Seventy', ' Eighty', ' Ninety' ];

    var iWordsLength=numReversed.length;
    var totalWords="";
    var inWords=new Array();
    var finalWord="";
    j=0;
    for(i=0; i<iWordsLength; i++){
        switch(i)
        {
        case 0:
            if(actnumber[i]==0 || actnumber[i+1]==1 ) {
                inWords[j]='';
            }
            else {
                inWords[j]=iWords[actnumber[i]];
            }
            inWords[j]=inWords[j]+' Only';
            break;
        case 1:
            tens_complication();
            break;
        case 2:
            if(actnumber[i]==0) {
                inWords[j]='';
            }
            else if(actnumber[i-1]!=0 && actnumber[i-2]!=0) {
                inWords[j]=iWords[actnumber[i]]+' Hundred and';
            }
            else {
                inWords[j]=iWords[actnumber[i]]+' Hundred';
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            if(actnumber[i]==0 || actnumber[i+1]==1) {
                inWords[j]='';
            }
            else {
                inWords[j]=iWords[actnumber[i]];
            }
            if(actnumber[i+1] != 0 || actnumber[i] > 0){
                inWords[j]=inWords[j]+" Thousand";
            }
            break;
        case 4:
            tens_complication();
            break;
        case 5:
            if(actnumber[i]==0 || actnumber[i+1]==1) {
                inWords[j]='';
            }
            else {
                inWords[j]=iWords[actnumber[i]];
            }
            if(actnumber[i+1] != 0 || actnumber[i] > 0){
                inWords[j]=inWords[j]+" Lakh";
            }
            break;
        case 6:
            tens_complication();
            break;
        case 7:
            if(actnumber[i]==0 || actnumber[i+1]==1 ){
                inWords[j]='';
            }
            else {
                inWords[j]=iWords[actnumber[i]];
            }
            inWords[j]=inWords[j]+" Crore";
            break;
        case 8:
            tens_complication();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        j++;
    }

    function tens_complication() {
        if(actnumber[i]==0) {
            inWords[j]='';
        }
        else if(actnumber[i]==1) {
            inWords[j]=ePlace[actnumber[i-1]];
        }
        else {
            inWords[j]=tensPlace[actnumber[i]];
        }
    }
    inWords.reverse();
    for(i=0; i<inWords.length; i++) {
        finalWord+=inWords[i];
    }
    document.getElementById('container').innerHTML=obStr+'  '+finalWord;
}
```

Include the below code in your HTML

```
<input type="text" name="rupees" id="rupees" />
<input type="button" name="sr1" value="Click Here" onClick="test_skill()"/>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Source: [Convert Amount in numbers to words in JavaScript](http://kuppalli.wordpress.com/2008/02/23/convert-amount-in-numbers-to-words/).