# How to display cash value in words using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Number to Word - jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7257575/number-to-word-jquery)

I want to show the total billed amount in receipt in words also. How to achieve it using jQuery?

Ex.

```
Item         Qty      Unit Price            Line Price
------------------------------------------------------
Pen           2         100                 200
Note Book     3          30                  90
------------------------------------------------------
Total                                       290
In Words: Rupees Two Hundred and Ninety Only
```

Comment: I tried by parsing each digit of the total amount.

Comment: So why not include the code you've written, and an explanation of what it's doing wrong?

Comment: [JavaScript Number to Words](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=en&safe=off&sclient=psy-ab&q=number%20to%20words%20javascript&oq=&gs_l=&pbx=1&fp=298692ad9c703b32&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&biw=1280&bih=737)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Working Demo](http://javascript.about.com/library/bltoword.htm)

```
<form name="test"><input type="text" size="18" value="" name="inum"><br><br><input type="button" onclick="test.rnum.value = toWords(test.inum.value);" value="To Words"><br><br><textarea rows="5" cols="40" name="rnum"></textarea></form><body>

<script type="text/javascript">
// American Numbering System
var th = ['', 'thousand', 'million', 'billion', 'trillion'];

var dg = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine'];

var tn = ['ten', 'eleven', 'twelve', 'thirteen', 'fourteen', 'fifteen', 'sixteen', 'seventeen', 'eighteen', 'nineteen'];

var tw = ['twenty', 'thirty', 'forty', 'fifty', 'sixty', 'seventy', 'eighty', 'ninety'];

function toWords(s) {
    s = s.toString();
    s = s.replace(/[\, ]/g, '');
    if (s != parseFloat(s)) return 'not a number';
    var x = s.indexOf('.');
    if (x == -1) x = s.length;
    if (x > 15) return 'too big';
    var n = s.split('');
    var str = '';
    var sk = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        if ((x - i) % 3 == 2) {
            if (n[i] == '1') {
                str += tn[Number(n[i + 1])] + ' ';
                i++;
                sk = 1;
            } else if (n[i] != 0) {
                str += tw[n[i] - 2] + ' ';
                sk = 1;
            }
        } else if (n[i] != 0) {
            str += dg[n[i]] + ' ';
            if ((x - i) % 3 == 0) str += 'hundred ';
            sk = 1;
        }
        if ((x - i) % 3 == 1) {
            if (sk) str += th[(x - i - 1) / 3] + ' ';
            sk = 0;
        }
    }
    if (x != s.length) {
        var y = s.length;
        str += 'point ';
        for (var i = x + 1; i < y; i++) str += dg[n[i]] + ' ';
    }
    return str.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');

}
    </script>
```

Comment: Brilliant answer....

Comment: How about for digits after decimal points ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang= "en">
<head>
<meta charset= "utf-8">
<title> Number Strings</title>
<style>
body{
    font-size:120%;
    margin:0 1em;   
}
h1 span{
    font-weight: bold; 
    color: navy; 
    font-size:smaller;
}
h2{
    border-top:5px navy ridge;
    margin:1em 0;
}
div{
    margin:1ex;
    position:relative;
}
label, input, button, textarea, select{
    font-size:1em;
    color:black;
    font-weight:600;
}
label, button{
    cursor:pointer;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;
    font-size:1em;
    font-weight:bold;
}
p{margin:1em 0}
button:hover, button:focus{
    color:red
}
button:disabled, button:hover:disabled, button:focus:disabled{
    cursor:default;
    color:gray;
}
textarea, textarea[readonly]{
    min-width:500px;
    width:90%;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    margin:1ex auto;
    font-weight:600;
    background-color:white;
    color:black;
    font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
}
#numstringDiv{
    background-color:white;
    color:black;
    position:relative;
    padding:1em;
    max-width:1200px;
}
@media all and(max-width:1000px){
    body{
        font-size:100%;
    }
}
</style>
<script>
/* US English words from numbers*/
Numword={
    cashwords: function(n){
        n= Number(n);
        if(!n) return NaN;
        var I= Math.floor(n),
        dec= n%1, str= '', r= '';
        str= I.toWords() || '';
        if(dec){
            dec= dec.toFixed(2)*100;
            r= dec.toWords();
        }
        if(I> 0){
            str+= ' dollar';
            if(I> 1) str+= 's';
            if(r) str+= ' and ';
        }
        if(r){
            str+= r+' cent';
            if(dec> 1) str += 's';
        }
        return str;
    },
    forget: function(){
        delete Numword.vocab;
        return true;
    },
    fracValue: function(s, prec){
        var I= 0, dec= 0, M=/(\d+ +)?(\d+)\/(\d+)$/.exec(s);
        if(M){
            if(M[1]) I= +(M[1].trim());
            dec= M[2]/M[3];
            if(typeof prec== 'number') dec= +(dec.toFixed(prec));
        }
        return I+dec;
    },
    getExponent: function(s, sign){
        var rx=  /(\d+(\.\d+)?|\.\d+)[eE]([+-]?\d+)/, num, pow,
        M= rx.exec(s);
        if(M){
            num= (+M[1]).toWords();
            pow= (+M[3]).toWords().ordinal();
            return sign+ num+ ' times ten to the '+ pow;
        }
        return NaN;
    },
    getWords: function(input, ord){
        s= String(input).trim();
        var d= s.replace(/(,| and)/g, ''),
        Num, I, dec, str= '', r= '',
        M, d2, d3, da,
        sign=  /^-.+/.test(d)? 'minus ':'';
        if(sign) d= d.substring(1);

        if(/infinity/i.test(s)) return sign? 'Negative Infinity':'Infinity';
        if(!s || !/\d/.test(s)) return '';

        if(d.charAt(0)=== '$'){
            d= Number(d.substring(1));
            return d? Numword.cashwords(d):'';
        }
        else if(d.indexOf('/')!= -1){
            return Numword.printFraction(d, sign) || '';
        }
        if(/^\d+\: *\d+/.test(d)){
            return d.match(/\d+/g).map(function(itm){
                return (+itm).toWords();
            }).join(' ');
        }
        d= d.replace(/[^\d\.eE+-]/g, '');
        da= Number(d);
        if(da> Math.pow(10, 17) || da< Math.pow(10, -6)) d= da.toExponential();
        else d= String(da);
        if(/\d[eE][+-]?\d/.test(d)) return Numword.getExponent(d, sign);
        str= da.toWords().trim();
        if(da=== Math.round(da) && ord) str= str.ordinal();
        return sign+str;
    },
    ordinal: function(){
        var ax, suffix, str= ' '+this.trim();
        if(str.charAt(str.length-1)== 'y') return str.slice(0, -2)+'tieth';
        var ax= str.lastIndexOf(' ');
        suffx= str.substring(ax);
        if(ax> 1) str= str.substring(0, ax);
        else str= ' ';
        switch(suffx.trim()){
            case 'one': return str+' first';
            case 'two': return str+' second';
            case 'three': return str+' third';
            case 'five': return str+' fifth';
            case 'eight': return str+' eighth';
            case 'nine': return str+' ninth';
            case 'twelve': return str+' twelfth';
            default: return str+suffx+'th';
        }
    },
    printFraction: function(d, sign, ret){
        var num, M=/(\d+\s+)?(\d+)\s*\/\s*(\d+)/.exec(d);
        if(!M) return NaN;
        num= M[1]? (+M[1]).toWords().replace(/ and /g, ' ')+' and ':'';
        num+= (+M[2]).toWords()+'-';
        if(M[3]=== '2') num+= 'half';
        else if(M[3]=== '4') num+= 'quarter';
        else num+= (+M[3]).toWords().ordinal();
        if(M[2]!== '1') num= num.replace(/([^s])$/, '$1s');
        return sign+num.replace(/ *\- */, '-');
    },
    strums:[
        'US-English',
        ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine',
        'ten', 'eleven', 'twelve', 'thirteen', 'fourteen', 'fifteen', 'sixteen', 'seventeen', 'eighteen', 'nineteen'],
        ['naught', 'ten', 'twenty', 'thirty', 'forty', 'fifty', 'sixty', 'seventy', 'eighty', 'ninety'],
        ['hundred', 'thousand', 'million', 'billion', 'trillion', 'quadrillion']
    ],
    toWords: function(ord){
        var W= Numword.strums, dec= '', N= '', I,
        A= [], L, tem, h, t, t2, o, str,
        sign= this<0? 'minus ':'',
        n= Math.abs(this);
        if(n && !isFinite(n)) return sign+' Infinity';
        I= Math.floor(n);
        if(n!== I) dec= String(n).split('.')
        if(dec[1]){
            dec= ' point '+ dec[1].split('').map(function(itm){
                return W[1][+itm];
            }).join(' ');
            if(I=== 0) return sign+'zero'+dec;
            else ord= false;
        }
        while(I> 0){
            tem= I%1000;
            I= (I-tem)/1000;
            if(tem=== 0) A.push('');
            else{
                str= '';
                t= tem%100;
                if(tem>= 100){
                    h= Math.floor(tem/100);
                    str= W[1][h]+' hundred ';
                }
                if(t> 0){
                    if(A.length== 0 && (h> 0 || I> 0)) str+= ' and ';
                    if(t<20){
                        if(W[1][t]) str+= W[1][t]+' ';
                    }
                    else{
                        t2= Math.floor(t/10);
                        o= t%10;
                        if(W[2][t2]) str+= W[2][t2];
                        if(o> 0 && W[1][o]) str+= ' '+W[1][o];
                    }
                }
                A.push(str);
            }
        }
        N= A.map(function(itm, i){
            if(!itm) return '';
            var tem= '';
            if(i> 0) tem= ' '+W[3][i];
            return itm+tem;
        }).reverse().join(' ');
        if(ord) N= N.ordinal();
        N= sign+ N.replace(/ion (?=\S+)/g, 'ion, ')+ dec;
        return N.replace(/ {2,}/g, ' ');
    }
}
Number.prototype.toWords= function(mod){
    return Numword.toWords.call(this, mod);
}
String.prototype.ordinal= function(){
    return Numword.ordinal.call(this);
}
/* equalizer for cross-browser support*/
String.prototype.trim= ''.trim || function(){
    return this.replace(/^\s+/g, '').replace(/\s+$/g, '');
}
Array.prototype.forEach= [].forEach || function(fun, scope){
    var T= this, L= T.length, i= 0;
    if(typeof fun== 'function'){
        while(i< L){
            if(i in T){
                fun.call(scope, T[i], i, T);
            }
            ++i;
        }
    }
    return T;
}
Array.prototype.map= [].map || function(fun, scope){
    var T= this, L= T.length, A= Array(L), i= 0;
    if(typeof fun== 'function'){
        while(i< L){
            if(i in T){
                A[i]= fun.call(scope, T[i], i, T);
            }
            ++i;
        }
        return A;
    }
}
/*end equalizer */
/*demo program */
window.Run={
    doc: function(what, pa, hoo, txt, sty){
        var tag, el, mod, ref;
        what= what.toLowerCase().split('_');
        tag= what[0], mod= what[1], ref= mr(pa);
        el= document.createElement(tag);
        if(hoo) el.id= hoo;
        if(sty) el.style.cssText= sty;
        if(ref){
            if(mod== 'b4') ref.parentNode.insertBefore(el, ref);
            else if(mod== 'bf' && ref.firstChild){
                ref.insertBefore(el, ref.firstChild);
            }
            else ref.appendChild(el);
        }
        if(txt) el.appendChild(document.createTextNode(txt));
        return el;
    },
    sayNext: function(hoo, text, css){
        Run.doc('br', hoo);
        return Run.doc('span', hoo, '', text, css);
    },
    zap: function(who){
        who= mr(who);
        while(who.lastChild) who.removeChild(who.lastChild);
    }
}
window.mr= function(hoo){
    if(typeof hoo== 'string') hoo= document.getElementById(hoo) || '';
    return (hoo.nodeType== 1)? hoo:null;
}
window.onload= function(){
    Numword.display= function(){
        var who= mr('strum_in'), v= who.value.trim(),
        v2, nw, n2, p2, w= '';
        if(!/(\d|Infinity)/i.test(v)) return;
        if(/^\.\d/.test(v)) v= '0'+v;
        if(/[$.\/eE-]/.test(v)){
            mr('ord_cbx').checked= false;
        }
        nw= Numword.getWords(v)+'';
        if(nw){
            if(mr('ord_cbx').checked) nw= nw.ordinal();
            Run.doc('p_bf', 'numword_div', '', v+'= '+nw);
        }
        who.value= '';
        mr('strum_in').focus()
    }
    Numword.sampler= function(){
        mr('ord_cbx').checked= false;
        var doc= Run.doc, A,B,C;
        A= ['150', '0.12', '65.35', '$65.45', '2012', '98.6', '897456971.25',
        '1 1/2', '12 and 3/4', '-9', '33 and 1/3','12:15','09:30',
        '1.155e+17', '1.222e3', '4.5e-10', '3.125e-3'].map(function(itm){
            return itm+'= '+Numword.getWords(itm);
        });
        B= [1, 2, 3, 21, 28, 112].map(function(itm){
            return itm+ '= '+itm.toWords().ordinal();
        });
        B.unshift('Ordinal format:');
        A= A.concat(B);
        Run.zap('numword_div');
        A.forEach(function(itm){
            p2= doc('p', 'numword_div', '',itm);
        });
        mr('strum_in').focus()
    }
    mr('toWordsBtn').onclick= Numword.display;
    mr('demoWordsBtn').onclick= Numword.sampler;
    mr('clearWordsBtn').onclick= function(){
        Run.zap('numword_div');
        mr('strum_in').focus();
    };
    setTimeout(function(){
        mr('strum_in').focus();
    },
    100);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id= "numstringDiv">
<h1> Numbers to Words<br>
<span> US- English version</span> </h1>
<div style= "max-width:900px; font-family:Georgia, 'Times New Roman',serif;">
<p> Besides digits, numerical input can include a negative sign(-50), dollar sign ($50.25),
decimal point (.), exponential (1.15e+25) or a real number with a division slash (1/2 or 9 3/4).</p>
<p> If you are expressing a positive integer you can return an ordinal number-
that is, 21 converts to "twenty first" and 12 to "twelfth".</p>
</p>
<p id= " "> Use the "Demo" button for some examples.</p>
</div>
<h3 style= "margin-top: 1em;"> Enter a number to convert to words</h3>
<div>
<label> Ordinal:<input id= "ord_cbx" type= "checkbox"> </label>
<input autocomplete= "off" size= "40" id= "strum_in" type= "text">
<button id= "toWordsBtn" type= "button" style= "margin-left: 1em;"> Convert</button>
<button type= "button" id= "demoWordsBtn"> Demo</button>
<button id= "clearWordsBtn" type= "button"> Clear</button>
</div>
<div style= "font-weight: bold;" id= "numword_div">
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```