# JavaScript: Convert number to Text (eg 18 -> "eighteen")

Tags: javascript, internationalization

Is there any metalanguage library to do this? I've been googling a lot, but didn't find any.

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529934/javascript-numbers-to-words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a page that does it, but it's not very complete: http://javascript.about.com/library/toword.js (Taken from http://javascript.about.com/library/bltoword.htm)

Another page that might give you some ideas: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/305408/Convert-numbers-to-words-in-English-and-Asian-form

I would also go off of the question Reflective linked.