# How to get text equivalent of a number in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How to convert numeric number to their text equivalent?

Example:
Suppose if I type 3 or 23 in the text box, I want their text equivalent of three or twenty three, is this possible?

Comment: May i know ,what did you try.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this answer for more details:

[JavaScript numbers to Words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529934/javascript-numbers-to-words)

And for a working implementation:

http://javascript.about.com/library/bltoword.htm

Answer (score 1):

This will help you to achieve your task.

[Number To Word](http://javascript.about.com/library/bltoword.htm)

Comment: Nice... and here I was about to program that.

Comment: Please put codes in your answer, not links.