# How to get amount in words?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am looking to echo an amount which is in numeric form as words on a receipt.
My code looks like this:

```
<tr>
<td width="77" style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">Center</td>
<td width="210" style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">Amount</td>
</tr><tr><td width="33" style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">1</td>
<td width="132" style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">
  <?php echo    $row[11] ?></td>
<td width="77" style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">
 <?php echo $row[12] ?></td>
  <td width="210" style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">
  <?php echo $row[3]   ?></td></tr></table>    <tr>
  <td height="32">   <p>Received with thanks Rs.....</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
</td>
```

So I want the value from Amount to be placed at "Received with thanks Rs.

Comment: As in 1 = one, 2 = two etc ?

Comment: yes i want to echo in words

Comment: The answers here may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529934/javascript-numbers-to-words

Comment: Before you post, search SO to see if the question has already been asked.  Most of the time, it has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well **`PHP`** does not support that (number to words) logic yet.

Make use of [`this`](http://www.karlrixon.co.uk/writing/convert-numbers-to-words-with-php/)

After including that...Rewrite your code like

```
<p>Received with thanks Rs. <?php echo convert_number_to_word($row[3]); ?></p>
```

Comment: Pass your amount value there.. I mean pass your `$row[3]` there