# How to replace the last two characters in a string to something else in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a string that is exactly three numbers, for example; 999. I want to replace the last two 9's with the words ninety-nine. I have looked searched around a lot, but for some reason I can't get anything to work. I also want to know how I would replace the first 9 with the words 
"nine hundred", but I don't want to have them done at the same time. It would be helpful if you could explain how it works, too, because I am relatively new to programming.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529934/javascript-numbers-to-words

Comment: @nzn I think that's far more advanced that what he's looking for. I think this is a substring level thing. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr

Comment: I'm new to programming like I said before, so I don't exactly get what is happening there. Could you explain it more simply? You don't have to worry about the HTML part or putting it in a function, but I just want a simple answer to the question. Thanks

Comment: So, you want us to write a program that changes Numbers to English values? I'm sure you can find something online, without us writing it for you. If not use `String.length` and `String.replace()`.

Comment: **Voting to close for being off-topic**:  _"Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. **Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work**, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)."_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you need all the numbers to be converted to english words. Not just 999. 999 was just an example.

You can do this with multiple `switch`.

Something like that:

You can see and the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9JMFX/)

```
var str="999";
var result="";

var first =str.charAt(0);//var first="9" in your example
switch (first){
case "9": 
result=result+"nine hundred "
break;
case "8": 
result=result+"eight hundred "
break;
case "7": 
result=result+"seven hundred "
break;
case "6": 
result=result+"six hundred "
break;
case "5": 
result=result+"five hundred "
break;
case "4": 
result=result+"four hundred "
break;
case "3": 
result=result+"three hundred "
break;
case "2": 
result=result+"two hundred "
break;
case "1": 
result=result+"one hundred "
break;        
default : result=result+"NaN"
}

var second =str.charAt(1);//var second="9" in your example
switch (second){
case "9": 
result=result+"ninety "
break;
case "8": 
result=result+"eighty "
break;
case "7": 
result=result+"seventy "
break;
case "6": 
result=result+"sixty "
break;
case "5": 
result=result+"fifty "
break;
case "4": 
result=result+"fourty "
break;
case "3": 
result=result+"thirty "
break;
case "2": 
result=result+"twenty "
break;
case "1": 
result=result+"ten "
break;        
default : result=result+"NaN"
}

var third =str.charAt(2); //var third="9" in your example
switch (third){
case "9": 
result=result+"nine"
break;
case "8": 
result=result+"eight"
break;
case "7": 
result=result+"seven"
break;
case "6": 
result=result+"six"
break;
case "5": 
result=result+"five"
break;
case "4": 
result=result+"four"
break;
case "3": 
result=result+"three"
break;
case "2": 
result=result+"two"
break;
case "1": 
result=result+"one"
break;        
default : result=result+"NaN"
}
alert(result);
```

Comment: what is the "var first =str.charAt(0);" doing in that?

Comment: it assignes to `var first` the first character of the sting-number you have. In you example 999 `var first="9"`

Comment: I have an array called values. How do I apply that to every object in the array?

Comment: You will have to make a `for-loop` assign each value of array in `var str`. Something like that `var str=values[i]`

Comment: Also, what things would I need to change to make it fit what I'm using? I tried only changing the word str to values[0], just to see if that would work for at least the fisrt object, but there is something else wrong that is causing my program to crash.

Comment: var str=values[0] should work. I can not figure out why your programm crush without seeing it.

Comment: That works, but then I tried using 123 as an example, and it said "one-hundred NaNNaN" I looked through it, but can't see anything wrong. Do you know?

Comment: Sorry, I just figured out my mistake on the last question, so you can forget that.

Comment: I cant see something wrong. It works fine for me. See http://jsfiddle.net/9JMFX/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
yourString = "999";

for (var x = 3; x > 1; x--) {
    yourString[x] = "nine hundred";
    x -= 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily replace the last two numbers at the end of a string with a regular expression:

```js
var value = "999";

value = value.replace(/\d{2}$/, "ninety-nine"); // 9ninety-nine
```

Note that this doesn't actually know that "99" is "ninety-nine". Neither does it know that "39" is "thirty-nine". [That task](https://www.google.com/search?q=code+golf+numbers+to+works&oq=code+golf+numbers+to+works&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l5.3015j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#es_sm=93&espv=210&q=javascript+number+to+word) is far more difficult to achieve than merely replacing parts of a string.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I replaced the "999" at the beginning with the name of my variable and tried alerting the variable, but it still says "999";

Comment: You would have to re-assign the resulting value to your original variable.

Comment: Huh? I don't get what you mean.

Comment: And I was able to figure out that it doesn't know that "99" is the same as "ninety-nine". Also, what would you change so that it replaces the first character with something else for a different part?

Comment: @user3130551 What would you want to replace the first character with?

Answer (score 0):

`var numericValue = 972`;

convert the number to a string first:

`var stringValue=numericValue+'';`

then you can use sub strings to find the individual values eg.:

`var hundreds = stringValue.substr(0,1);`

Where the first parameter `(0)` is the start position and the second `(1)` is the number of characters in the string you're searching for.

then you can pick the string you're looking for from an object.:

```
var hundredsObj = {
'9':'nine hundred',
'8':'eight hundred',
'7':'seven hundred',
'6':'six hundred.....'}
```

`var hundredsStr = hundredsObj.hundreds`