# Convert numbers to printable string value using Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, numbers

I was wondering if there is already any javascript function to convert a int value to its string value. I am sorry but I don't the exact term to use it and hence please follow below examples:

if I pass 2, it should return "two"
if I pass 11, it should return "eleven"

I assume there would be a limit and my requirement is to find those number values upto 3 digits (0 - 999)

I want to save time by not creating a mapping string set manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is nothing existing that will allow you to do this, but there are plenty of solutions out there. See this link for a bunch of examples: [JavaScript numbers to Words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529934/javascript-numbers-to-words)

Comment: Thanks for confirming and sharing the way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

There's no inbuilt API for this in Javascript. However, writing your own function shouldn't be that difficult, since once you get past the teens, there is a fixed pattern (twenty one, thirty one, forty one etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [that](http://www.dzone.com/snippets/javascript-convert-integer), it can convert numbers up to 1000