# Total amount in number to words conversion

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have two fields in my form as shown bellow

```
Total amount: <input type="text" value="1230"></input>
<br>
<textarea>amount in words goes here..</textarea>
```

Now, I need to display the value amount of my first input field to textarea as one thousand two hundred thirty.

Thanks

Comment: Please get familiar with the basic concept of angularjs.

Comment: delete the question , its good of you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no role of Angular in this. Its simple logic that you have to use. This Question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529934/javascript-numbers-to-words) for javascript.

**UPDATE**: [This](http://javascript.about.com/library/bltoword.htm) is another solution I found for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

To get you started:
Use ng-model to bind to model data and ng-change to react on any change in your input:

```
Total amount: <input type="text" ng-model="data.text" ng-change="countWords()" value="1230"></input>
```

in your controller:

```
$scope.data = {text:"", count:0};
$scope.countWords = function(){
  $scope.data.count = [count the words of $scope.data.text...]
};
```

then display the value in your view:

```
<textarea>{{data.count}}</textarea>
```