# How do i make my code for converting numbers to words in javascript work?

Tags: javascript

So the HTML in my code is just part of creating a basic game that generates a random number and turns it to a word, so the user has to type in the number its it numerical form.

Can anyone help as I can't seem to get my head around how to make the conversion work or suggest a better way?

```js
function btnStart_onClick() {
    lblrdm.innertext = parseInt(Math.random() * 999);
    parQuest.innerText = "What is this number in Digits? " + Convert(lblrdm.innertext);
    btnStart.disabled = true
    btnCheck.disabled = false
}

function Convert(num) { // THIS IS WHERE IM STUCK
    var ones = new Array('', ' one', ' two', ' three', ' four', ' five', ' six', ' seven', ' eight', ' nine', ' ten', ' eleven', ' twelve', ' thirteen', ' fourteen', ' fifteen', ' sixteen', ' seventeen', ' eighteen', ' nineteen');
    var tens = new Array('', '', ' twenty', ' thirty', ' forty', ' fifty', ' sixty', ' seventy', ' eighty', ' ninety');
    var hundred = ' hundred';
    var output = '';
    var numString = "num.toString()";

    if (num < 20) {
        output = ones[num];
        return output;
    }

    if (numString.length == 3) {
        output = ones[parseInt(numString.charAt(0))] + hundred;
        output += tens[parseInt(numString.charAt(1))];
        output += ones[parseInt(numString.charAt(2))];
        return output;
    }

    output += tens[parseInt(numString.charAt(0))];
    output += ones[parseInt(numString.charAt(1))];

    return output;
}
```

```html
<p id="parQuest"></p><!-- basic html -->
<input id="btnStart" type="button" value="Start" onclick="btnStart_onClick()" />
<input id="txtNum" type="text"> 
<input id="btnCheck" type="button" value="Check" onclick="btnCheck_onClick()" disabled />
<p id="parMsg"></p>
<p id="lblrdm" type="text"" ></p>
```

Comment: How should the word look for say... 126? "One Hundred and Twenty Six" or "One Hundred Twenty Six"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript numbers to Words](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529934/javascript-numbers-to-words)

Comment: @AdamJeffers either or is fine by me, the problem is when i press my start button all i get is undefinedundefined, if i sound new its because i am haha

Comment: See @davidkonrad's comment, a possible solution already exists.

Comment: @AdamJeffers i have already checked that thread which got me to where i am now

Comment: When you append `lblrdm.innertext` to `"What is this number in Digits?"`, `lblrdm.innertext` has not been defined, hence `undefined`

Comment: @AdamJeffers i thought this line was generating my random number into "lblrdm"   lblrdm.innertext = parseInt(Math.random() * 999)

Comment: `var numString = "num.toString()"` definitely doesn't do what you think it does. Remove the quotes.

Comment: Yes but `innertext` is not the same as `innerText`... notice the case

Comment: @AdamJeffers i didn't even notice!

Comment: @Sulthan Working a charm now thank you!

Answer (score -2):

A rough implementation of the function

```js
const getString = (value, size, next) => {
    let stringValue = "";

    switch (value) {
        case 1:
            stringValue = "One";
            break;
        case 2:
            stringValue = "Two";
            break;
        case 3:
            stringValue = "Three";
            break;
        case 4:
            stringValue = "Four";
            break;
        case 5:
            stringValue = "Five";
            break;
        case 6:
            stringValue = "Six";
            break;
        case 7:
            stringValue = "Seven";
            break;
        case 8:
            stringValue = "Eight";
            break;
        case 9:
            stringValue = "Nine";

        default:
            break;
    }

    if (size === "Ten") {
        switch (value) {
            case 2:
                stringValue = "Twenty";
                break;
            case 3:
                stringValue = "Thirty";
                break;
            case 4:
                stringValue = "Forty";
                break;
            case 5:
                stringValue = "Fifty";
                break;
            case 6:
                stringValue = "Sixty";
                break;
            case 7:
                stringValue = "Seventy";
                break;
            case 8:
                stringValue = "Eighty";
                break;
            case 9:
                stringValue = "Ninety";
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    if (size === "Hundred" && next) {
        return `${stringValue} ${size} and`;
    } else if (size === "Hundred") {
        return `${stringValue} ${size}`;
    } else {
        return stringValue;
    }
};

const convertToWords = (value, old) => {
    let size;
    let num;
    let next;

    if (!value) {
        return "";
    }

    switch (value.toString().length) {
        case 2:
            size = "Ten";
            next = value % 10;
            num = Math.floor(value / 10);
            break;
        case 3:
            size = "Hundred";
            next = value % 100;
            num = Math.floor(value / 100);
            break;
        default:
            size = "Unit";
            next = 0;
            num = value;
            break;
    }

    let response;
    if (num === 1 && size === "Ten") {
        switch (next) {
            case 1:
                response = "Eleven";
                next = 0;
                break;
            case 2:
                response = "Twelve";
                next = 0;
                break;
            case 3:
                response = "Thirteen";
                next = 0;
                break;
            case 4:
                response = "Fourteen";
                next = 0;
                break;
            case 5:
                response = "Fifteen";
                next = 0;
                break;
            case 6:
                response = "Sixteen";
                next = 0;
                break;
            case 7:
                response = "Seventeen";
                next = 0;
                break;
            case 8:
                response = "Eighteen";
                next = 0;
                break;
            case 9:
                response = "Nineteen";
                next = 0;
            default:
                response = "Ten";
                next = 0;
                break;
        }
    } else {
        response = getString(num, size, next);
    }

    if (old) response = `${old} ${response}`;

    if (next) return convertToWords(next, response);

    return response;
};

console.log(convertToWords(999));
// Nine Hundred and Ninety Nine
```