# Returning Numeric Input as String Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, javascript-objects, number-formatting

I am having issues with spaces. Also, dashes are needed in between numbers such as fifty-four; however, I am getting dashes behind numbers like fifty- thousand.

Also, I require no blank spaces after the output, but I keep having issues outputting with spaces.

Any ideas?

PS: I have studied [Convert digits into words with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14766951/convert-digits-into-words-with-javascript) - I would like my version to work.

```js
function number2words(n) {
  a = ['', 'one ', 'two ', 'three ', 'four ', 'five ', 'six ', 'seven ', 'eight ', 'nine ', 'ten ', 'eleven ', 'twelve ', 'thirteen ', 'fourteen ', 'fifteen ', 'sixteen ', 'seventeen ', 'eighteen ', 'nineteen '];
  b = ['', '', 'twenty', 'thirty', 'forty', 'fifty', 'sixty', 'seventy', 'eighty', 'ninety'];
  c = ['', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten', 'eleven', 'twelve', 'thirteen', 'fourteen', 'fifteen', 'sixteen', 'seventeen', 'eighteen', 'nineteen'];


  if ((n = n.toString()).length > 9) return false;
  num = ('000000000' + n).substr(-9).match(/^(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{1})(\d{2})$/);
  if (!num)
    return;

  var str = '';
  dash = '-';

  if (c[num[5][1]] == '')
    dash = '';

  if (n <= 19 && n != 0)
    return c[n];
  else if (n == 0)
    return 'zero';
  else if (n == 20 || n == 30 || n == 40 || n == 50 || n == 60 || n == 70 || n == 80 || n == 90)
    return b[n[0]];
  else
    str += (num[1] != 0) ? (a[Number(num[1])] || b[num[1][0]] + '-' + a[num[1][1]]) + 'million ' : '';
  str += (num[2] != 0) ? (a[Number(num[2])] || b[num[2][0]] + '-' + a[num[2][1]]) + 'hundred ' : '';
  str += (num[3] != 0) ? (a[Number(num[3])] || b[num[3][0]] + '-' + a[num[3][1]]) + 'thousand ' : '';
  str += (num[4] != 0) ? (a[Number(num[4])] || b[num[4][0]] + '-' + a[num[4][1]]) + 'hundred' : '';
  str += (num[5] != 0) ? ((str != '') ? ' ' : '') + (a[Number(num[5])] || b[num[5][0]] + dash + a[num[5][1]]) : '';
  console.log(str[str.length - 1], str.length);

  if (str[str.length - 1] == " ") {
    var sl = str.slice(0, str.length - 1);
    return sl;
  }
  return str;
}
console.log(number2words(15007));
console.log(number2words(464097));
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529934/javascript-numbers-to-words

Comment: So two people found two duplicates in less than one minute.

Comment: My problem isn't the duplicate. My question is based on the original answer however with edits I need help figuring out how to address small bugs as explained.

Comment: Please see my updates to your question - it is now a [mcve]. It shows one issue. Can you add more that shows leading and trailing spaces?

Comment: I have added edits with the numbers to run showing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**

```
function number2words(n) {
  a = ['', 'one ', 'two ', 'three ', 'four ', 'five ', 'six ', 'seven ', 'eight ', 'nine ', 'ten ', 'eleven ', 'twelve ', 'thirteen ', 'fourteen ', 'fifteen ', 'sixteen ', 'seventeen ', 'eighteen ', 'nineteen '];
  b = ['', '', 'twenty', 'thirty', 'forty', 'fifty', 'sixty', 'seventy', 'eighty', 'ninety'];
  c = ['', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten', 'eleven', 'twelve', 'thirteen', 'fourteen', 'fifteen', 'sixteen', 'seventeen', 'eighteen', 'nineteen'];


  if ((n = n.toString()).length > 9) return false;
  num = ('000000000' + n).substr(-9).match(/^(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{1})(\d{2})$/);
  if (!num)
    return;

  var str = '';
  dash = '-';

  if (c[num[5][1]] == '')
    dash = '';

  if (n <= 19 && n != 0)
    return c[n];
  else if (n == 0)
    return 'zero';
  else if (n == 20 || n == 30 || n == 40 || n == 50 || n == 60 || n == 70 || n == 80 || n == 90)
    return b[n[0]];
  else
    str += (num[1] != 0) ? (a[Number(num[1])]  || b[num[1][0]] + '-' + a[num[1][1]]) + 'million ' : '';
    str += (num[2] != 0) ? (a[Number(num[2])]  || b[num[2][0]] + '-' + a[num[2][1]]) + 'hundred ' : '';
    str += (num[3] != 0)  ? (a[Number(num[3])]  || b[num[3][0]] + '-' + a[num[3][1]]) + 'thousand ' : '';
    str += (num[4] != 0) ? (a[Number(num[4])]  || b[num[4][0]] + '-' + a[num[4][1]]) + 'hundred' : '';
    str += (num[5] != 0) ? ((str != '') ? ' ' : '') + (a[Number(num[5])] || b[num[5][0]] + dash + a[num[5][1]]) : '';

   str = str.split("  ").join(' ');
   str = str.split("-thousand").join(" thousand");

 if(str[str.length-1] == " "){
   var sl = str.slice(0, str.length-1);
   return sl;
 }

  return str;
```

Comment: So what was the issue? And why not post a running version in a snippet?

Comment: I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try bellow.

```js
var a = ['','one ','two ','three ','four ', 'five ','six ','seven ','eight ','nine ','ten ','eleven ','twelve ','thirteen ','fourteen ','fifteen ','sixteen ','seventeen ','eighteen ','nineteen '];
var b = ['', '', 'twenty','thirty','forty','fifty', 'sixty','seventy','eighty','ninety'];

function inWords (num) {
    if ((num = num.toString()).length > 9) return 'overflow';
    n = ('000000000' + num).substr(-9).match(/^(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{1})(\d{2})$/);
    if (!n) return; var str = '';
    str += (n[1] != 0) ? (a[Number(n[1])] || b[n[1][0]] + '-' + a[n[1][1]]) + 'million ' : '';
    str += (n[2] != 0) ? (a[Number(n[2])] || b[n[2][0]] + '-' + a[n[2][1]]) + 'hundred ' : '';
    str += (n[3] != 0) ? (a[Number(n[3])] || b[n[3][0]] + '-' + a[n[3][1]]) + 'thousand ' : '';
    str += (n[4] != 0) ? (a[Number(n[4])] || b[n[4][0]] + '-' + a[n[4][1]]) + 'hundred ' : '';
    str += (n[5] != 0) ? ((str != '') ? 'and ' : '') + (a[Number(n[5])] || b[n[5][0]] + '-' + a[n[5][1]]) + 'only ' : '';
    return str;
}

console.log(inWords(999999999));
console.log(inWords(1095));
```

> Copy Form [Convert digits into words with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14766951/convert-digits-into-words-with-javascript) Done some changes for your output.

Comment: I can see `ninety-nine million ninety-nine hundred ninety-nine thousand nine hundred and ninety-nine only` in console.