# I can't understand a thing

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I can't find a way to make a list with words instead of numbers. For example:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    console.log(i + '');
}
```

in this code it will give all the numbers from `0` to `9`.

And if I want to put the words how to do it?

Comment: Just to clarify the task - you have to list the numbers, in words, from 0 to 9 (zero to nine)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are *a lot* of ways to accomplish this task.

One way is by storing the numbers in an array and then just outputting the number at each index of the array:

```js
let numbers = ['Zero', 'One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'Six', 'Seven', 'Eight', 'Nine'];

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    console.log(`${i} ${numbers[i]}`);
}
```

You could also use `if` statements or a `switch` statement (shown below):

```js
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var output = i + ' ';
    
    switch (i) {
        case 0:
          output += 'Zero';
          break;

        case 1:
          output += 'One';
          break;

        case 2:
          output += 'Two';
          break;
        
        default:
          output += 'And so on...';
          break;
    }
    
    console.log(output);
}
```

If may be better to clarify the exact need in your case as this example will clearly only work for numbers between 0 and 9.

Here is a post with some clever answers that provide for many more numbers as words: [JavaScript numbers to Words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529934/javascript-numbers-to-words)