# javascript function converting thousand digit to word

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, enums

I am working on a project where user inputs numbers in ten thousand format `[10000,20000, ..., 90000]` or in hundred format `[100, 200,..., 900]`.
I have to convert the input number to word. What I have done so far is:

1. first check the length of the string
2. get the first two digit of the string

If the user inputs *200* then in another text box it should show *two hundred*, if the user input *50000* then it should show *fifty thousand*.
.I am confused how to proceed. I have created enum for these, I do not know how to use them.

```js
const singleDigit = {
  // for hunderd format
  "10" : "one",
  "20" : "two",
  "30" : "three",
  //...
  "90" : "nine",
}

const doubleDigit = {
  // for ten thousand format
  "10" : "ten",
  "20" : "twenty",
  "30" : "thirty",
 // ...
  "90" : "ninty",
}

function changeToWord() {
  var amount = document.getElementById("fname").value;
  let len_ = amount.length;
  let firstDigit = amount.substring(0, 2);
  console.log("length: " + len_ + "substring: " + firstDigit);
  if (len_ == 5) {
    switch (firstDigit) {

    }
  }
}
```

```html
<label for="fname">Amount In Figure:</label><br>
<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br>
<label for="lname">Amount In Words:</label><br>
<input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" onfocusin="changeToWord()"><br><br>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please edit it to provide a [mcve]

Comment: lots of discussion here: [JavaScript numbers to Words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529934/javascript-numbers-to-words)

Comment: Object element assignments use `:` not `=`