# How to Convert Number to Text In JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

After Taking Numbers From Users e:g (1,2,3,4)  how can I convert them into text e:g(One, Two, Three) Pardon if If not specific in my question

I Wanted tio use Switch but I Think I do need some Automation like if Someone type 1005 he'll get a return of one thousand and five

Comment: You need to write a complex algorithm to do it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript numbers to Words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529934/javascript-numbers-to-words)

Comment: Another option in terms of npm libraries is https://www.npmjs.com/package/n2words.
No dependencies and it's currently maintained.

Answer (score 0):

Try this npm package: `https://www.npmjs.com/package/number-to-words` and see if it satisfies you problem

Answer (score 0):

you can use a package as mentioned above, or you can use this as well

```
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/saqib1144/pen/vbGEyd)
```